# BufferedReader : does this design against Liskov substitution principle?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

As BufferedReader derive from Reader. But in the BufferedReader, it add some extra public methods : such as readLine(), 
Looking forward your comments
thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think that violates LSP?

Comment: I had a misunderstand about LSP. I thought that LSP asking the sub class must not override the super class's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is that any entity of a type, `B`, *more derived* than another type, `A`, can be used to fulfil any behaviour expected of an entity of type `A`. In other words, if `B` is a subclass of `A`, an instance of `B` should do everything expected of an instance of `A`.

This way, a variable assignment like `A a = new B();` will not cause any surprising behaviour. The instance of `B` can be treated as an instance of `A`, so the type system protects the program from unexpected behaviour.

If, however, `A` has a method `foo()`, and `B` overrides this method with new behaviour not expected from an instance of `A`, the above assignment, which is fine as far as the type system is concerned, can still lead to unexpected behaviour.

In the case of `BufferedReader`, which extends `Reader`, the `BufferedReader` implements everything in `Reader` as expected, and merely adds further behaviour. If we use the assignment `Reader reader = new BufferedReader(...);`, the class is designed so that any code using the `reader` object, an instance of `Reader`, need not know what kind of `Reader` (in this case a `BufferedReader`) the instance is. The fact that more behaviour is available from the `BufferedReader` class is irrelevant; here we only know (and only need know) that we have a working `Reader`. In this way, it satisfies the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not against Liskov Substitution principle. Still it is type of `Reader`. You can substitute it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not, as long as you do not **override** any functionanlity but only **extend** it. Basically, the LSP is fulfilled, as long as you could just use your child class instead of the parent class and the whole application still works the exact same way.

See also: [What is the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)